# Spring Boot File Download with Range header (partial download)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, file-io

I am developing Spring Boot Rest service for file download (either complete file or in ranges) The request from the controller is passed on to the service layer where i do processing on the file and have to return it.

Option 1: 
I could read the FileInputStream Byte by Byte and write it directly to output stream. But in that option, i will have to pass the response object to service layer, which i dont want to do(as service layer should be decoupled from web components).

Option 2:
Passing the entire byte array from service layer to controller might also not be a good option as i am dealing with very large files.

Option 3: 
In case of returning the entire file, i could pass the FileInputStream to ResponseEntity and spring can take care of streaming but i also
need to address the case where i return a range of bytes from the file depending on the Range header.

Any inputs or direction with respect to this will be very helpful. Let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to go with something else. This is what I did in my project:

1. Extract the fromByte/toByte values from the Range header,
2. Declare the service method semantics as following:

   - `byte[] getMediaFileContent(Long/UUID <fileId>, Long fromByte, Long toByte)`,
3. Read the specified bytes range from the target file in the service method and return the byte array,
4. Build the proper ResponseEntity<> manually from that byte[] in the Controller, also specifying the required headers:

   - `"Accept-Ranges": "bytes"`
   - `"Content-Type": <content-type>` (ex. image/x video/y or application/octet-stream)
   - `"Content-Length": <range length>`
   - `"Content-Range": String.format("bytes %s-%s/%s", fromByte, toByte, fileFullLength)`

Maybe there would be other suggestions, but this has nothing complicated and worked perfectly...

To read the file into the specified range of bytes you can use the following code:

```
byte[] readByteRange(File file, long start, long end, boolean inclusive) throws IOException {
        try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int nRead;
            while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                bufferedOutputStream.write(data, 0, nRead);
            }
            bufferedOutputStream.flush();
            if (inclusive) {
                ++end;
            }
            byte[] result = new byte[(int) (end - start)];
            System.arraycopy(bufferedOutputStream.toByteArray(), (int) start, result, 0, (int) (end - start));
            return result;
        }
```